# Kubernetes-pods/services are in pending state due to not enough resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

So i have been setting up my kubernetes cluster so for that i need my pods to to be in running status.
But I have been trying start some more pods by scaling them but its showing me this message in events section and is in pending state:

`0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 Insufficient memory, 3 Insufficient cpu.`

I got to know that this is happening becasue of not enough resource in my master node and worker node.
And i am stuck here. Please try to give some solution.

Comment: Are you trying to test the deployment or not? if you are testing, you can use `minikube` on your local machine

Comment: Either make resources available in any of the node to allow scheduling OR add toleration to the pod as shown in the error message. Check out taint n toloration for details.

Comment: there is no option other adding more resources or remove if any other extra deployment running that you can clean up. it wont be good idea to change taint and schedule PODs on master node so better to add more worker node.

Comment: I already have 3 worker nodes cant have more than that. Have to adjust in that itself

Comment: Scaling up requires more resources. You might change the resource requests and imits on your pods before scaling up

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set the CPU and memory requests of the containers too high. Lower them or remove them at all for testing.